# Why sql server can't clear local parameter declared in the cursor when looping?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, coalesce, declare

I have been working on a cursor which looks like below. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
Declare @Pnr nvarchar(7)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT B.Pnr FROM SomeTable B
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Pnr   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN
/*some stuff*/
declare @Remark nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Remark=COALESCE(@Remark + ', ', '') + Remark from OtherTable where Pnr=@Pnr
/*some stuff*/
   FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Pnr   
END   
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I thought that `@Remark` would be null again if it is declared every loop.
But the query keeps previous value if it gets null for `@Remark`

Solution is simple i can set null on the every loop but i am wondering why declaring doesn't clear the local variable in loop.

Example:

```
OtherTable
--------------
Pnr | Remark
---------------
2 | aaaaaaaa
2 | bbbbbbbb
2 | cccccccc
3 | qqqqqqqq
3 | wwwwwwww
```

Results:

```
Pnr | Remark
------------
1 | NULL
2 | aaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbb, cccccccc
3 | qqqqqqqq, wwwwwwww
4 | qqqqqqqq, wwwwwwww = should be NULL
5 | qqqqqqqq, wwwwwwww = should be NULL
```

Comment: Variable declarations don't participate in control flow at all in T-SQL. This is one of the language's delightful "features".

Comment: Really. I was thinking it like other programming languages. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is because when assigning from a query and there is no value returned, `SELECT` will not make the assignment so the value of the variable will not be changed.

Use `SET` instead so that when there is no value returned, the variable will be `NULL`.

However in your case, you want to concatenate all `Remark`s for each `Pnr`. Using a `CURSOR`, there is no way you can do this using `SET`. But here is an alternate and faster way:

```
SELECT
    s.Pnr,
    t.Remark
FROM SomeTable s
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Remark
        FROM OtherTable
        WHERE Pnr = s.Pnr
        FOR XML PATH(''),  type).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
     1, 2, '') AS Remark
)t
```

Comment: What do you suggest if i would like to assign a lot of variable from a query?

Comment: Avoid cursors? Not joking... There are really very few situations where a cursor is the right choice...

Comment: @Shnugo, huh? I think you misplaced your comment.

Comment: @FelixPamittan, well, this was meant for the OP... Forgot to add his nick...  And you are right. This should be below the question...

Comment: @Shnugo, good. I thought I missed something. I, for one, is against `CURSOR`. But I do believe that there are times when `CURSOR` is the right choice. This one's not it.

Comment: @Shnugo and Felix Pamittan, I think i forgot to specify the some stuff is 250-300 line. Cursor should be there. There is no using or avoiding cursor issue. I just shared little part of code. And the query gets a lot of variable. I just wonder why declaring variable in the cursor keeps previous variable for each loop. Because variables are declared inside of cursor. Thanks for responses.

Comment: As I've said in my answer, it's because of the nature of `SELECT` when assigning a variable, wherein if the results is `NULL`, the variable assignment will not take place and thus the previous value will be retained. You should reset the variable to `NULL` to fix this, `SET @Remark = NULL`.

Comment: @EsatEmreDemirel, To your question in comment above ("assign a lof of variables"). You can declare your variables and the write SELECT @var1=col1, @var2=col2,@var3=col3,... FROM SomeWhere. But you knew this probably...